# For loops not executing scan.nextInt correctly

Tags: java, for-loop, logic, syntax-error

This is a program I am working on for class. After writing most of the program I am now trying to run it and it seems I have a logical error. For some reason the computer will just execute up until the first for loop, and then ignore the scan.nextInt methods where I try to prompt the user to enter values into the array.

**EDIT : new problem : Now, when I run the program the loop that is not executing correctly is the 2nd for loop. It returns the total number correct as the total correct possible no matter what you enter. Also returns 0% correct :(**

***Edit 2: I fixed the problem for the percent correct part, but I still am at a loss for the correct way to go about comparing the input values for the correct answers entered when grading the quiz... it always returns the number correct to be the total number of questions, regardless of the whether they are right or not.***

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class gradingQuizzes {

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int numQuestions;           // number of questions on quiz
    int numCorrect = 0;         // number correct of entered values
    int correctAnswer;          

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the amount of questions in the Quiz: ");
    numQuestions = scan.nextInt();
    int[] key = new int[numQuestions];      // creates an array for the key to the quiz

    // Prompts the user to enter values into the key array
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the correct answer to question number " + (i + 1) + " : ");
        key[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Please enter the answers for the quiz to be graded: ");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");

    // 'for' loop asking for the correct answer for each question on the quiz
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Question " + (i + 1) + " answer: ");
        correctAnswer = scan.nextInt();
        if (correctAnswer == key [i]);
        {
            numCorrect++;       // increments the number correct for each match to the key
        }
    }
    // Creates a variable to compute the percent correct on the quiz
    double percentCorrect = (numCorrect / (key.length));

    System.out.println("The number correct is: " + numCorrect);
    System.out.println("The percent correct: %" + percentCorrect);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `new int[0]` (note that `numQuestions` is initialized with 0)?

Comment: You're welcome. Also, next time don't add the language in the title since it already is in the tags.

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing the array with a 0 size (note that you're initializing `numQuestions` with 0). Just move the array initialization after getting the `numQuestions` value form user input:

```
numQuestions = scan.nextInt();
int[] key = new int[numQuestions];
```

---

If you want to assign  `double` values using `int`/`long` to a `double` variable, you should cast the `int`/`long` to `double` or multiply it by `1.0` (literal), otherwise the floating point result would be an `int`/`long`. Modify this part of the code:

```
double percentCorrect = ((numCorrect * 1.0) / ((key.length + 1) * 1.0) );
```

If you want to print formatted text to output, you should use [`System.out.printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). I'll write an example of the final code (regarding language grammar):

```
//System.out.println("The percent correct: %" + percentCorrect);
System.out.printf("The percent correct: %% %.2f\n", percentCorrect);
```

From the link above:

- `%%` will print the `%` symbol
- `%.2f` will print the floating point number using 2 fixed decimals
- `\n` will print a line break

Comment: Edit 2: I fixed the problem for the percent correct part, but I still am at a loss for the correct way to go about comparing the input values for the correct answers entered when grading the quiz... it always returns the number correct to be the total number of questions, regardless of the whether they are right or not.

Comment: doesn't this suffice to print the percent as well? double percentCorrect = (numCorrect / (key.length) * 100);

Comment: Also, my problem now is that in the 2nd for loop I'm not sure how to compare multiple values of "correctAnswer" to key [i]. for some reason it is incrementing numCorrect up to the max value each time, instead of just incrementing when correctAnswer == key [i] for that specific instance of the for loop.

Comment: @TommyD use a debugger to find that problem or post a new question. Get used to post **one** question for post. If you want a code review, go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are using `key.length`. the array does not have any element so will return 0.

Comment: It would be helpful if you suggested a fix too, not just what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared

```
int[] key = new int[numQuestions];
```

when numQuestions is 0

This will work

```
    numQuestions = scan.nextInt();

   key = new int[numQuestions];
```

For the second part of your question, there is a semicolon at the end of the if statment.
remove it

```
if (correctAnswer == key [i]);
```

Comment: @TommyD - Check         if (correctAnswer == key [i]);
remove the semicolon at the end of the if statment

Answer (score 0):

```
int numQuestions = 0;       // number of questions on quiz
    int numCorrect = 0;         // number correct of entered values
    int correctAnswer;          
    int[] key = new int[numQuestions];
```

Here numQuestions  is declared as 0 .Change it to anothe valid.